# ResponseEntity serialized as json with another value

Tags: json, spring, rest

I have two Microservices with Spring Boot.

**Microservice 1**

It is a RestController with a method. This method returns a ResponseEntity. The use case that I am testing returns in this ResponseEntity the following --> new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<ServiceProvided> addService(@RequestBody ServiceProvided serviceProvided);
```

**Microservice 2**

It is another RestController with a method which calls the Microservice 1 via a client (@FeignClient ServiceProvidedManagementClient).

*RestController*

```
@Autowired
private ServiceProvidedManagementClient serviceProvidedManagementClient;

@RequestMapping(value = "/create", consumes = "application/json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<ServiceProvided> createApplication(@RequestBody String service) {
    ServiceProvided serviceProvided = ServiceMapper.convertToServiceProvided(service);
    return serviceProvidedManagementClient.addService(serviceProvided);
}
```

*Client*

```
@FeignClient(url = "localhost:8080")
public interface ServiceProvidedManagementClient {
@RequestMapping(value = "/services", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<ServiceProvided> addService(@RequestBody ServiceProvided serviceProvided);
}
```

**The problem**

If I call directly the Microservice 1 via SoapUi for example. I get what I expected. Nothing as JSON response and in Raw Response --> HTTP/1.1 **422** Unprocessable Entity

But if I call the Microservice2 (which calls the Microservice 1), I get another response:

*As Json*

> {    "timestamp": 1468221824521,    "status": 500,    "error":
>   "Internal Server Error",    "exception": "feign.FeignException",
>   "message": "status 422 reading
>   ServiceProvidedManagementClient#addService(ServiceProvided)",
>   "path": "/services/create" }

As Raw --> HTTP/1.1 **500** Internal Server Error

**Question**

1. It is possible to get the same response of Microservice 1 in the
   Microservice 2 (no json and same exception)?
2. Why is serializing the response of Microservice 1 in a json object
   in Microservice 2 and why is getting a HttpStatus of 422 and turning
   in HttpStatus of 500 with a message of HttpStatus 422 (like it can
   be see in the response as Json of Microservice 2)

Comment: Because the client throws an exception, that exception is processed by the default exception handling. An exception by default leads to a status 500. If you want to handle it differently either handle it in the code that is using the client or provide an exception handler that unwraps the exception and uses that to create the response.

Comment: Thanks, it was that. If you put as answer, I can set it as correct.